# Prove that a function is piecewise constant

Tags: integration, analysis

Assume $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are all positive functions. Assume that $h(x)$ and $g(x)h(x)$ are both integrable. If $f(x)$ is piecewise constant and

$$f(T) \int_0^Th(t)dt = \int_0^Tg(t)h(t)dt$$

for each $T>0$, does it follow that $g(x)$ is also piecewise constant?

My attempt:

First assume that $f(x)=C$. Let $0=t_0...t_N=T$. In the limit as $N$ increases we have:

$$C \sum_{i=0}^N H_i = \sum_{i=0}^N g(t_i)H_i$$

where $H_i :=h(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_{i})$

My idea is that if this true for any $t<T$ we also have:

$$CH_1=g(t_1)H(t_1)$$

Then we can show that

$$C(H_1+H_2) = g(t_1)H_1+g(t_2)H_2$$

and so on.

But I don't know how to show that properly consdering the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $f(T)$ on LHS?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Corrected.

Comment: One obvious counter-example is obtained by taking $h(t)\equiv 0$ and $g$ arbitrary.

Comment: What if h(x) is positive (sorry, one more edit)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Subtracting one side from the other in this type of situation helps, because both algebra and analysis have special roles for $0$. Here, we'd write the hypothesis$$0 = f(T)\int_0^T h(t)\,dt - \int_0^T g(t)h(t)\,dt = \int_0^T\bigl[f(T)-g(t)\bigr]h(t)\,dt.$$Now, if I understand, $h$ is an arbitrary integrable function. Can you think of a particularly enlightening choice?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. $h$ is an arbitrary positive functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take the question literally, then the answer is no. That is because we can alter $g$ on any null set while preserving the integral equation (adding something like $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$ makes $g$ not piecewise constant). However, $g$ is equal to $f$ almost everywhere.

Start by looking at the interval $[0,a]$ where $f$ is constant. Then consider the reformulation of Andrew D. Hwang above, namely, consider $$ F(t)=(f(0)-g(t))h(t).$$ We know that $$ \int_0^T F(t) dt =0 $$ for all $0\leq T<a$. Pick any point $x_0\in (0,a)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon) \subseteq (0,a)$. Then we get

$$ \int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon} F(t)= \int_0^{x_0+\varepsilon} F(t) dt - \int_{0}^{x_0-\varepsilon} F(t)dt = 0-0=0. $$

By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem we get that $F(t)=0$ for almost every $t \in (0,a)$. However,

$$ 0=F(t)=(f(0)-g(t)) h(t) $$
implies (as $h>0$) that
$$ g(t)=f(0) $$
for almost all $t\in (0,a)$. We can iterate this process to get that $g$ coincides with $f$, a piecewise constant function, almost everywhere.